# ListCreateAPIView POST with an annotated field that's in serializer not model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm building a simple budgeting app to work on learning Django & React. I've used DRF to build an API to create and get transactions from the database. I'm currently calculating the total running balance on the fly when I do my GET. This has been working well, but when I do a POST I get an error that my dynamic balance field is required since that field is in my serializer. How can I get around this?

views.py

```
class CreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """This class defines the GET & POST behavior of the rest api."""

    queryset = Transaction.objects.all()

    # This is the balance that's calculated on the fly
    queryset_with_balance = queryset.annotate(balance=Window(Sum('amount'),
                                                             order_by=F('created_time').asc())).all().order_by('-created_time')

    serializer_class = TransactionSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Save the post data when creating a new transaction."""
        serializer.save()

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset_with_balance
```

serializers.py

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    balance = serializers.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=19)

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('id', 'date', 'payee', 'category',
                  'amount', 'balance', 'created_time', 'modified_time')
```

models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    payee = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    amount = MoneyField(max_digits=19,
                        decimal_places=2,
                        default_currency='USD')    
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Do you need this `balance` field while `HTTP POST` ?

Comment: you can move queryset_with_balance or only annotate to `def get_queryset(self):`

Comment: Balance is only needed on the GET. I'm not storing that in the DB.

Comment: @brewcrazy Check my answer below :) Hope that will solve the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `balance` field as ***`read_only`*** as below,

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    balance = serializers.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=19, read_only=True)
    # your code
```

From the [DRF doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#read_only)

> Read-only fields are included in the API output, **but should not be included in the input during create or update operations**.